# Does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \zeta(n + 1)$ converge to $-1$?

Tags: riemann-zeta, digamma-function

According to my calculations $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \zeta(n + 1) = -1$$ but for example [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20from%20n%3D1%20to%20infinity%20of%20%28-1%29%5En*zeta%28n%2B1%29) says that the sum doesn't converge, so have I done anything wrong (my calculations down below)?

My calculations:

Start with the taylor series for the digamma function:
$$\psi(z) = -\gamma - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\zeta(n+1)(1-z)^n$$
Plugging in $2$:
$$\psi(2) = -\gamma - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\zeta(n+1)(-1)^n$$
But since $\psi(2) = 1 - \gamma$, we have:
$$1 - \gamma = -\gamma - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\zeta(n+1)(-1)^n$$
And we have arrived at our result that: 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \zeta(n + 1) = -1$$

Comment: The taylor series for the digamma function converges only for $|z|\lt 1$

Comment: @Hrodelbert With me $\sum_{n=1}^N(-1)^n\zeta(n+1)$ goes like this:$$-1.644934067,-0.4428771637,-1.525200397,-0.4882726423,-1.505615704,-0.4972664269,-1.501343783,-0.4993353902,-1.500329965,-0.4998357768,-1.500081863,-0.4999591500,-1.500020398,-0.4999898099,-1.500005092,-0.4999974549,...$$It thus oscillates between -.5 and -1.5

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე You are right, that's what you get for restricting to even numbers without thinking...It seems the sum oscillates between $-3/2$ and $-1/2$, so does not converge

Comment: Yeah that's what I did wrong, but it's still an interesting sum!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall that $\zeta(s) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \tfrac{1}{k^s}$, so $\lim_{s \to \infty} \zeta(s) = 1$. Thus, the terms of $\sum (-1)^{n} \zeta(n+1)$ don't go to zero, and the sum doesn't converge.

However, there is a sense in which you are right. Let's break up your sum as $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n} \left( \zeta(n+1)-1 \right).$$

We have
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n} \left( \zeta(n+1)-1 \right) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{k^{n+1}}.$$
I claim that this sum is absolutely convergent; to check this, note that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^{n+1}} = \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{1/k^2}{1-1/k} = \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k(k-1)}$$
which converges. Thus, we may rearrange the sum into 
$$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{(-1)^n}{k^{n+1}} = \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{-1/k^2}{1+1/k} =  \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{-1}{k(k+1)} = \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{k+1} - \frac{1}{k} \right)= - \frac{1}{2}.$$

The sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n$ does not converge, but it is summable by any of a number of techniques for treating [divergent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series), such as Abel summation or Cesaro summation. In the sense of those summation methods, we have $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n = \tfrac{-1}{2}$. So, in the sense of those summation methods, your sum is $\tfrac{-1}{2} + \tfrac{-1}{2} = -1$.

Comment: Thank you very much!